# css overflow is not working properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, overflow

So I am writing a script for a live drawing area. It is a work in progress right now, but here is the css for the area:

```
#canvas{
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    cursor:none;
    overflow:hidden !important;
    margin-top:50px;
    width:400px;
    height:300px;
    border:1px #000 solid;
}
```

Now clearly, with the `important` tag on `overflow:hidden`, anything outside the 400x300 box that has to do with drawing should not show, **but it does!!!**

[here is a jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HEnuj/4/) so you can see all the code!

## How you can see what I mean:

Just click on the thing at the top that says paintbrush and follow the instructions in the `p` tag for drawing. Then go outside of the box and see how it continues to draw.

note:

I use `$('#canvas').prepend(content)` to get the drawing into the drawing area, so it makes no sense that it would show up in areas outside it when there is an `overflow:hidden`. any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Weird , but it helps: add `position:relative` to `#canvas` stylesheet:

```
#canvas {
  /* ... */ 
  position: relative;
  /* ... */ 
}
```

(JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/HEnuj/7/)
I'm not CSS specialist so i have no logical explanation , except of something like "*if some elements has `position:absolute` relatively to their parent so parent must be `position:relative`*" , thats what i remember.

Comment: @RyanSaxe  how many dots you can draw? is browser crashes sometimes?

Comment: You can draw a lot, but the more you draw, the slower they come in...I'm not sure how to deal with that yet

Comment: @RyanSaxe i think it is because they are dom elements actually , even they are "empty" nodes they do eat memory. may be you should try Canvas API ?

Comment: No, I want to do this on my own, it's a project I gave myself. I thought `remove` would clear it though...